# Linux mmap() with MAP_POPULATE, man page seems to give wrong info

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

It looks to me like `MAP_POPULATE` is not just for private mappings, in contradiction to what the man page says:

> MAP_POPULATE (since Linux 2.5.46) Populate (prefault) page tables for
>   a mapping. For a file mapping, this causes read-ahead on the file.
>   Later accesses to the mapping will not be blocked by page faults.
>   MAP_POPULATE is only supported for private mappings since Linux
>   2.6.23.

Based on my cursory inspection of the Linux kernel source for [mmap.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/mmap.c), it looks like `MAP_POPULATE` has absolutely no relationship with `MAP_PRIVATE` whatsoever in [versions going back as far as 2.6.34](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/diff/mm/mmap.c?diffval=2.6.34;diffvar=v).

Here is an excerpt of the latest code from [mmap.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/mmap.c) as of the 3.14 kernel implementation:

```
...
1364         addr = mmap_region(file, addr, len, vm_flags, pgoff);
1365         if (!IS_ERR_VALUE(addr) &&
1366             ((vm_flags & VM_LOCKED) ||
1367              (flags & (MAP_POPULATE | MAP_NONBLOCK)) == MAP_POPULATE))
1368                 *populate = len;
1369         return addr;
...
```

Am I wrong in my observation?

Comment: I read that remark as "before 2.6.23, MAP_POPULATE was not supported for private mappings" (with no information about MAP_POPULATE for non-private mappings).

Comment: I guess it can be interpreted that way also. Maybe "they" need to change the language so that it is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 12):

The wording has been updated since you asked the question:

```
Before: MAP_POPULATE is only supported for private mappings since Linux 2.6.23.
After:  MAP_POPULATE is supported for private mappings only since Linux 2.6.23.
```

In other words, you can use MAP_POPULATE for private mappings, but you need at least Linux 2.6.23.

Hope this clarifies it!

Comment: I don't think the wording helps with the ambiguity at all. When a colleague and I read this the other day we interpreted it as `MAP_POPULATE is supported (for private mappings only) since Linux 2.6.23.` That is, it seems to be saying that it only supports private mappings in later versions of the kernel. I'd recommend something like `Since Linux 2.6.23 MAP_POPULATE works for both private and shared mappings. Prior to 2.6.23, only shared mappings were supported.`